# CKEditor no carga plugin de video

Tags: javascript, jquery, ckeditor

Estoy usando CKEditor 4.8.0

El problema aquí es que no carga el plugin de video

he realizado estas configuraciones en el config.js del ckeditor

Plugin video:

```
config.extraPlugins = 'video';
```

Plugin HTML5 Video

```
config.extraPlugins = 'html5video';
```

Ninguna de esas dos configuraciones me ha servido.

Codigo html

```
<form action="" method="post">
<textarea name="editor" id="editor">
</textarea>
<br>
<input type="button" value="Subir" name="boton" onClick="agregar();">
<script>
var editor = CKEDITOR.replace('editor');
</script>
</form>
```

Comment: Por favor revise en la consola del navegador (F12) para revisar si hay errores. Si es posible, [edit] y agregue el código fuente en su pregunta. Saludos.

Comment: @MauricioAriasOlave ya revise en consola y no hay errores

Comment: Según este foro, [CKEditor](https://ckeditor.com/old/forums/Plugins/HTML5-Video) tiene algunos problemas con los videos. Si quieres seguir usando CKEditor, consulta esta [pregunta en Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47348624/4092887).

Answer (score 0):

Ya resolvi este problema solo volvi a descargar la version y listo agregue cualquier plugin video o html5video y si lo carga, pero ahora al usar el plugin html5video me encuentro con que no carga el video como puedo solucionar esto sin usar ckfinder??